# Disable Default Sorting in linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list with values ***A1,A2,A3,A4...A10...*** The values get from database are in this order. But when **linq** is used the order changes to ***A1,A10,A2,A20,A3.....*** Even without using order by the default sorting is in ascending order. Is there any way to disable this default sorting?

```
 public static string[] GetCompleteAutoCompleteItemsUsingDataTable(this DataTable AutoCompleteTable, string strPrefixText, int Count)
        {
            string AutoCompleteFieldName = AutoCompleteTable.Columns[1].Caption;
            List<string> objlistMain = new List<string>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPrefixText))
            {
                strPrefixText = strPrefixText.ToLower().RemoveSpecialCharactersFromString();
                objlistMain = (from dr in AutoCompleteTable.Select("[" + AutoCompleteFieldName + "] <> ''").AsEnumerable() where dr.Field<string>(AutoCompleteFieldName).ToLower().RemoveSpecialCharactersFromString().StartsWith(strPrefixText) select dr.Field<string>(AutoCompleteFieldName)).Take(Count).ToList<string>();

                if (objlistMain.Count < Count && AutoCompleteTable.Rows.Count > objlistMain.Count)
                {
                    List<string> objlist = (from dr in AutoCompleteTable.Select("[" + AutoCompleteFieldName + "] <> ''").AsEnumerable() where dr.Field<string>(AutoCompleteFieldName).ToLower().RemoveSpecialCharactersFromString().Contains(strPrefixText) && !objlistMain.Contains(dr.Field<string>(AutoCompleteFieldName))  select dr.Field<string>(AutoCompleteFieldName)).Take(Count - objlistMain.Count). ToList<string>();
                    foreach (string str in objlist)
                    {
                        objlistMain.Add(str);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                objlistMain = (from dr in AutoCompleteTable.Select().AsEnumerable()  select dr.Field<string>(AutoCompleteFieldName)).Take(Count).ToList<string>();
            }
            return objlistMain.Distinct().ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: And what order do you want?

Comment: I dont want it to be sorted

Comment: And maybe what you call ascending order is the insertion order?

Comment: No its not in insertion order

Comment: There is NO such thing like *"Default Sorting in linq"*. Rephrase the question and update the code example - the one you included contains a couple LINQ queries plus manual processing, so it's totally unclear what are you talking about.

Comment: If you don't want the results sorted, you're done. Because no sorting means the sorting is not determined and your application code can do anything with the order. If the order of elements matter, you have a sorting requirement and should be able to work that out in your code.

Comment: Check your database, I think that's record store in this order, like linq return records

Answer (score 0):

If you do not sort the data once you retrieve it from the database and you see that the data is sorted, then that might be because of the `SQL-query` that is executed against the database. Any differenc `SQL-query` might result in differen ordering. This is because `JOIN`ing to other tables or `GROUP`ing results, and the use of `INDEXES`.

Generally you cannot be sure that by not using `ORDER BY` in `SQL-query` that the result is not sorted; it might be.

p.s. A topic to dive in in your case is also the `natural sorting`. This sorts `A1, A2, A10` instead to `A1, A10, A2`.

Comment: The sql result is in the order A1,A2,...A10 after using linq it changes